# Docker Hub automated build failure. Local build is fine

Tags: build, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I've created a [dockerfile](https://github.com/DavidForster/symphonycms-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) to take an official php/apache image, add a bunch of dependencies and clone a GitHub repo, which works great when building a container image locally, but fails when I push it to GitHub and trigger an automated build at [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/davidforster/symphonycms/).

The command which fails is the git clone

```
RUN git clone git://github.com/symphonycms/symphony-2.git /var/www/html
```

and the reason for failure (according to Git) is

> Step 5 : RUN git clone git://github.com/symphonycms/symphony-2.git
>   /var/www/html     && git checkout --track origin/bundle     && git
>   submodule update --init --recursive     && git clone
>   git://github.com/symphonycms/workspace.git     && chown -R
>   www-data:www-data *
>
> [91mfatal: destination path '/var/www/html'
>   already exists and is not an empty directory.

Can someone explain why there is no problem building locally but a failure at the hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the image that you are pushing has the `/var/www/html/` directory in it (and probably has the git repo in it).

Try this in your docker file to make sure the directory doesn't exist:

```
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html
RUN git clone git://github.com/symphonycms/symphony-2.git /var/www/html && git checkout --track origin/bundle && git submodule update --init --recursive && git clone git://github.com/symphonycms/workspace.git && chown -R www-data:www-data
```

Comment: Thanks, this addition fixes the automated build. My question is, shouldn't the parent containers be the same?? How come the HTML directory was empty already when I was building locally?

Comment: Well did you push the container or just the Dockerfile?  If you pushed the container the parent would be whatever you pushed.  If you pushed just the docker file and use the `FROM` directive, then the parent would be whatever you specify in that `FROM` directive.

Comment: I'm not just pushing my built container to the Docker Hub (that would have never been an issue). I'm building from the DockerFile locally (with success, even without the 'rm'), committing it to Git and pushing it up to GitHub, which is then triggering an automated build at the Docker Hub. Surely in both build environments the php:5-apache parent FROM container _should_ be identical, no?

Comment: @DavidForster yeah, should be the same. So something is off, it could be that the parent is coming from a different registry.

Comment: I have since discovered that not only is the /var/www/html folder different in content but it also has a different owner (root instead of www-data) when built automatically by Docker Hub. I have raised a subsequent support ticket with them.